# Check if one of the range conditions is a point

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

The conditions below yield to a Real point (or hyperplane):

1. `x == 1`
2. `x == 1 && y == 2`
3. `x == 1 && y < 2`
4. `x < 1 && y == 2`
5. `x < 1 && y == 2 && z < 5`

In other words some of the variables in equations / inequalities above cover only single value rather than range. For obvious reasons equations / inequalities below have all of their variables covering a range and thus the equations themselves represent not a point not a hyperplane but a volume.

5. `x == 1 && y == 2 || (x < 1 && y < 2)`
6. `x == 1 && y == 2 || (x < 0 && y < 0)`

Is there a way to test if condition belongs to a first or second case (is it a hyperplane or a volume) in Mathematica? I.e. Suppose you have a piecewise function consisting a mixture of conditions above and you want to distinguish conditions based on previously described explanation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) with [`RegionDimension`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDimension.html).

```
RegionDimension@ImplicitRegion[x == 1 && y == 2 || (x < 1 && y < 2), {x, y}]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

The above is a surface.

```
RegionDimension@ImplicitRegion[x == 1 && y == 2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

The above is a point.

Hope this helps.